# Pick duplicate record within grouping records?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an history table in which duplicate records are entered due to history_date_time column.
Because of some process or loading issue i get this duplicate record.
I used a query like

```
SELECT (col1, col2), COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY (col1, col2)
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

I grouped a records based on `col1` and `col2` but the problem is
i may have different column with different records. `I want to pick unique records within the grouping records by checking all columns`

How can i achieve this... using oracle sql query.. `i need query`

Sorry i dont have a proper table structure right now.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Alternatively, if it must be a "group" of columns, perhaps you meant something like this?

```
SELECT col1 ||'-'|| col2 col, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col1 ||'-'|| col2
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

Sample data would help.